# Infinite series expansion of $e^{2πi}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I was analysing $\zeta$(2) and I thought:-
$$\frac{π²}    {6}-1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}= \frac{π²}{6}\tag{1.1}$$
Here "1" is the first term of the infinite series.

Transposing $$\frac{π^2}{6}$$
To the right hand side,
$$-1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}= \frac{π²}{6}-\frac{π²}{6}= 0$$

Now transposing -1 to the right hand side,
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}=0+1$$
Equation (1.1) is another thing my question is:-
Is equation (1.1) is valid?
If yes then it is infinite series expansion of $$e^{2πi}$$

Because $$1= e^{2πi}$$

I have only visual proof of equation (1.1)
I am new here so if you detected any problem please let me know.

Comment: It's true $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left((n-1)^{-2}-n^{-2}\right)=1$, but that's got nothing to do with verifying $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2\pi i)^k}{k!}=1$.

Comment: But I need prove of equation (1.1) and second equation is kind of weird any explanation

Comment: Look up telescoping series. The second issue really should be in another question, but follows from $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$.